# Opensource UAV no fly zone

Tags: gps, maps

I am creating a software framework for autonomous UAVs. I was looking for various options that can give me a list of restricted areas. Buit apparantly I found the following:

Companies like Mapbox,AirMap,Hover,RCFlyMaps,DJI,3D Robotics,The Atlanta Journal-Constitution, Drone Zones (UK), NoFlyDrones (UK), UAV Zones, FlyNoFly Map and FAA provides maps that can show there is a airport nearby.

But is there not even a single provider who give UAV restricted regions in formats such as JSON object that can be used by the developer to design an auto-piolet?

Comment: Thank you so much for the link! This is exactly what I asked. 

But, it seems that the JSON has more information for US and has less for Europe. And 5 mile airport circle blocked the place I am working, but apparently there were so many drone testing going around :( Do you know any other project exactly similar to this?

Comment: Hello,
I think something happened for the comment you gave, can you post it again as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time of research I found the only one open source framework. It is from Mapbox. It is available in the link https://github.com/mapbox/drone-feedback/tree/master/sources/geojson